# Checking global arrays in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a question and hope you have the answer to it. When submitting data from one form to the next page for processing, is it better to check the global array as a whole e.g.

```
isset($_POST)
```

or

```
isset($_POST['value'])
```

My question is applicable to all global arrays like `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, `$_FILES`, etc. The reason is that I get a lot of bad handling to deal with caused by checking if certain variables are checked or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST` and the other [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are always defined, so `isset($_POST)` and such is meaningless (it will always return `true`).

The second check is what you should use.

Answer (score 2):

`isset($_POST)` is always `true`, you need to check at least one `key` inside `$_POST`.

If the `$_POST['value']` is blank it will be also set so you need to check if that variable isn't empty `if($_POST['value'] != '')` too